# Yum Update has issues with Perl packages

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I am running RedHat Linux on aws. When I run a yum update it ends with the following issues. How do I resolve this?

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 4:perl-libs-5.10.1-127.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS/6.3)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-127.el6
           Removing: 4:perl-5.10.1-127.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS/6.3)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-127.el6
           Updated By: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (base)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 6 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.x86_64 is a duplicate with db4-4.7.25-17.el6.x86_64
1:perl-Module-Pluggable-3.90-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 has missing requires of perl = ('4', '5.10.1', '136.el6_6.1')
1:perl-Pod-Escapes-1.04-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 has missing requires of perl = ('4', '5.10.1', '136.el6_6.1')
4:perl-libs-5.10.1-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 is a duplicate with 4:perl-libs-5.10.1-127.el6.x86_64
4:perl-libs-5.10.1-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 has missing requires of perl = ('4', '5.10.1', '136.el6_6.1')
3:perl-version-0.77-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 has missing requires of perl = ('4', '5.10.1', '136.el6_6.1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you're running Red Hat but your yum shows that you have CentOS repositories. Please check that out first.

If you have yum-plugin-priorities installed (you can check this with)

```
[root ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, keys, list-data, priorities, replace, versionlock
...
```

you'll need to add

```
priority=1
```

to [base] and [updates] in /etc/yum.repos.d/Centos-Base so it looks something like:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
priority=1
```

Then run (the cache cleaning may not be necessary but for good measure:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

I had this issue for a while and that was the solution to this:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 4:perl-libs-5.10.1-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
Error: Package: 4:perl-Time-HiRes-1.9721-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
Error: Package: 1:perl-Digest-SHA-5.47-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
Error: Package: 1:perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS-2.2003.0-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
Error: Package: 1:perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.021-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
Error: Package: 4:perl-devel-5.10.1-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
Error: Package: 1:perl-Package-Constants-0.02-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
           Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (@CentOS-6 - Base/6.6)
               perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

ChrisN's answer helped me fix similar issue. I didnt have priorities plugin installed, but I was missing a section for **"updates"**. I had disabled the default **CentOS-Base repo** and installed custom one. And that one was missing [updates] section. So I added [one](http://mirror/centos/6/updates/x86_64). After that, **`yum update`** fixed the issue, and I had no trouble installing subsequent packages dependent on that version of perl.